# What is the difference between token creation failure and verification failure? (Stripe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Looking at stripe docs:

> The following fields are entirely optional and cannot result in a
>   token creation failure:
>
> ```
> name: cardholder name
> address_line1: billing address line 1
> address_line2: billing address line 2
> address_city: billing address city
> address_state: billing address state
> address_zip: billing postal code as a string (e.g., "94301")
> address_country: billing address
> ```
>
> Although optional, we highly recommend collecting the user's postal
>   code as address and postal code verifications help reduce fraud.
>   Simply provide an address_zip value and enable declines on
>   verification failures in your account settings.

So for example `address_zip` will not result in a token creation failure but can result in a verification failure? What's the difference between the two (functionally)?

Answer (score 0):

Token creation failures occur because the bank failed the charge because of an invalid card number, bad expiry, bad CVC or invalid address/zip etc; however, as I understand it, it's up to the bank to decide if a charge is valid, so it may accept a charge where the address/zip, CVC or apparently even the expiry are incorrect.

Stripe provides settings in your Dashboard that will 'force' charges to fail when the address/zip check fail and/or when the CVC check fails to help reduce fraudulent charges.  When these are enabled, a charge will fail if you try to use a token where those checks failed, but the token will still be created.

You can read more about Stripe's address verification [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-avs) - and there are some related questions on the right that are worth investigating too.

Comment: Thanks. Is there someone where I can read more indepth about these verification failures? Such as how does stripe check if addresses and zip codes are valid in countries other than the US, and if this verification changes if I have the user submit their country?